# Testing a directive with .$on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have written a couple of controllers using the .$on and have been able to successfully test them, see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8cwcdPc26PVAURmVFR8t?p=preview

However, i now have a directive using .$on in its link function:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){

            scope.$on("step1", function(event) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('step3');
                scope.hidden = false;
                scope.shown = false;
            });
            scope.$on("step2", function(event) {
                scope.msg = '';
                scope.errorCase = false;
                scope.infoCase = false;
            });
            scope.$on("step3", function(event) {
                scope.hidden = true;
            });
        },
        template: 
                        '<div class="wrapper">' +
                            '<p>{{ msg }}</p>' +
                        '</div>'
    };
});
```

I have written the following test:

```
describe('myDirective', function () {
    var $scope, compile, element;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element("<section my-directive></section>");
        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should initialise step1', function (){
        var sub_scope = $scope.$new();
        sub_scope.$emit('step1');
        expect($scope.hidden).toBeFalsy();
        expect($scope.shown).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

However the test is not running at all so no error is displaying. I have followed the same approach as how i the controller however i think this is incorrect for a directive. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be great to have a plunker of the non-working test. The approach is the right one, I mean it is ok to broadcast in test an event so that your directive code would be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new scope for your directive based on your definition:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
// ... Your code ...
        scope: {}, // This is a new isolated scope for the directive
// ... Your code ...
    };
});
```

In your existing test, your `$scope` variable is the scope of the parent creating the directive. You need to get the scope of the directive in your test by calling ['isolateScope'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods). See forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aX5t5l2JZ8TTeVeCHNm9?p=preview)

```
it('should initialise step1', function (){
    var directiveScope = element.isolateScope();
    var sub_scope = directiveScope.$new();
    sub_scope.$emit('step1');
    expect(directiveScope.hidden).toBeFalsy();
    expect(directiveScope.shown).toBeFalsy();
});
```